# Resizing a partition did not update the df output

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

I resized a partition using `fdisk` (tried with `cfdisk` too) (deleted the partition and created another, larger, with the same start). Rebooted and now `fdisk`/`cfdisk` shows the new size, but `df -h` shows the smaller value.

It is a 16GB SD card in a Banana Pi (Raspberry clone) running Ubuntu 16.04.

The pictures show the same partition `/dev/mmcblk0p2` with different sizes in the 2 tools:

cfdisk:
[image: cfdisk]

df -h:
[image: df -h]

Comment: Please do not add pictures/images of text. Consider adding this information as text and format it accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making the partition larger manually, doesn't grow the file-system. You wil have to run something like:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

for extX file-systems.